# go not running program with name package_test.go

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have following code under package *pack1*. Name of file is `pack1.go`

```
package pack1

var Pack1Int int = 42
var pack1Float = 3.14

func ReturnStr() string {
    return "Hello world!"
}
```

And following code in main program. Name of file is `package_test.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "./pack1"
)

func main() {
    var test1 string
    test1 = pack1.ReturnStr()
    fmt.Printf("Return string from pack1 : %s\n", test1)
    fmt.Printf("Integer from pack1 : %d\n", pack1.Pack1Int)
}
```

When I try to run it with command `go run package_test.go` I get following error:

`go run: cannot run *_test.go files (package_test.go)`

But if I rename file to `abc.go` then I am getting proper output i.e.

```
Return string from pack1 : Hello world!
Integer from pack1 : 42
```

I am curious about what is wrong with using `package_test.go` as file name. 
For code with only main package this name is working fine.

Is this a bug in Go or I am doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't name your program files as `*_test.go` as this is part of integrated Go [testing system](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/)

> To write a new test suite, **create a file whose name ends _test.go** that contains the TestXxx functions as described here. Put the file in the same package as the one being tested. The file will be excluded from regular package builds but will be included when the “go test” command is run. For more detail, run “go help test” and “go help testflag”.

Just rename `package_test.go` to `packagetest.go`

Answer (score 15):

Not a bug, it's designed so. `go run` detects the `_test` files and consider them as test files for a package, test files will be compiled as a separate package, and then linked and run with the main test binary.
It's recommended to put your package file to `GOPATH/src/PACK_NAME/`, then run your `*_test.go` with `go test`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it a little ?

Comment: This seems like a silly language feature, as it means you can't store _test.go files in the same directory as the rest of your go package. Unless I'm misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

For ***BASH***

Run `go run PATH_TO_FILES/!(*_test).go`

**NOTE**

If you get an event not found error when running this command, you probably need to enable extended globbing in your bash terminal.

Run `shopt-s extglob`

after you Run `go run PATH_TO_FILES/!(*_test).go`

---

For those using ***ZSH***

`setopt extendedglob`                                                    # to get help regarding globbing

next

`foo*~*bar*`                                                # match everything that starts with foo but doesn't contain bar

So with my case, `go run PATH_TO_FILES/*~*_test.go*`

Answer (score -1):

if you are using linux:

```
go run `ls PATH_TO_FILES/*.go | grep -v _test.go`
```

it workes for me.